# java server push image on android device

Tags: java, tcp, android

I am trying to make a java tcp server that will send an image to all connected android devices.

Then the devices should set this image as background. i know how to send an image from java server to android device . but i want to make the android listen for incoming stream all the time and whenever it get the image it will set it as background.

```
public void listenForIncomingImage() {
        Thread InComImage = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        inComImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mySocket
                                .getInputStream());
                        MainActivity.setImage(inComImageBitmap, true);
                        Log.d("Bitmap", "Bitmap receviced and sent to method");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        InComImage.start();

    }
```

this is on the android side it send the image to Mainactivity.

```
public void imageUpdate() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            while(imageCheck = true)
                            myImage.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
                            imageCheck = false;

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

this is the tread am using in the mainactivity to update the UI however the app wont update and it crash. i think the thread is over loading the memory and causing the app to crash.

any idea what is goin on ? or a better way for implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but there are some errors in your loop:

```
 while(imageCheck = true)
     myImage.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
     imageCheck = false;
```

1 you assign imageCheck= true instead of checking imageCheck==true

2 you do not use paranteses {} so the imageCheck=false is not inside your while loop

3 your loop could run forever

4 you are doing endless calls of runOnUIThread as the 'while(true)' will  continu running: do you need this while loop?

Comment: oh this is why. i missed the extra = and the {}